# Both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are finite, what about $f''(x)$?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is a differentiable function for which $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)$ both exist and are finite. I wonder is there any counterexacmple such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f''(x)\not =0$.

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists, doesn't that mean that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = 0$?

Comment: A standard construction is $f(x)=x^-1\sin(g(x))$ for an appropriately quickly growing function $g$. I think in this case $g(x)=x^{3/2}$ works.

Comment: @Keshav not necessarily. Consider $f(x)=\sin(x^3)/x$. So the derivative oscillates as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: @Jiexiong687691 Ah I see. But in that case the limit of $f'$ doesn't exist right?

Comment: @Keshav yes, that's true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$$
f(x) = \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}
$$
Extended analytically to $f(0) = 1$.
Then
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 0
\\
\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f'(x) = 0
$$
But these two limits do not exist:
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} f''(x),\qquad \lim_{x \to -\infty} f''(x)
$$
because they have limsup $4$ and liminf $-4$.